# “functionName” is not a function while sending function as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pagination

I am new to React and Typescript, and I have some blog with content, and I am trying to add pagination to it.

I watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYCa1F-OWmk&t=961s) and wrote that component for paigination:

```
import React from 'react'



export const Pagination = (totalPagesX:any, paginate :any) => {
    const pageNumbers=[];
    

    const size=Math.ceil(totalPagesX.totalPages);
   
    
for (let index = 1; index <=size; index++) {

    pageNumbers.push(index);
}

    return (
        <nav>
            <ul className='pagination'>
                {pageNumbers.map((number)=>(
                    <li key={number} className='page-item'>
                    <Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={paginate} />
                            {number}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

now the parameter paginate is a function in my App class:

```
export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {


    state: AppState = {

        currentPage: 1,
        totalPages:'10',

    }




    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            totalPages: await api.getTotalPages(),
        });
                }


      paginate=(pageNumber:number)=>{console.log("number",number)};
     

    render() {
        const { currentPage, totalPages } = this.state;
        return (<main>
            <ThemeProvider>
                <Page />

            </ThemeProvider>
            
                <Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={this.paginate} />
            </footer>
        </main>)
    }}
```

but every-time I try to go to the next page I get this error:

```
> TypeError: paginate is not a function 
19 | <ul className='pagination'>  
> 20 |{pageNumbers.map((number)=>(21 |<li key={number}
> className='page-item'>
> > 22 |<a className='page-link' href='!#' onClick={(number) => paginate(number)}>
>| ^  23 |{number}24 |</a>   25 | </li>
```

Comment: And I am using ":any" type because if remove it I will get another error: " Binding element 'paginate' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: I see many errors in your code. If I fix all of those for you, you won't learn anything. Can you try the tutorial again? Maybe you will fix some of those by yourself and then, the rest of the problems, we can help you fix. E.g. `(totalPagesX:any, paginate :any)` and `<Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={this.paginate} />` and `paginate=(pageNumber:number)=>{console.log("number",number)};` and `<Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={this.componentDidMount} />` is wrong. And I don't understand why you are invoking `Pagination` component inside `Pagination` component?

Comment: ok I'll try again then, thank you!!

Comment: You are using <Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={this.paginate} /> inside Pagination component. No need ot this. You can manage this using li tag.

Comment: @ajeet-shah, Thank you again.I fixed everything you told me to, except (totalPagesX:any, paginate :any), because then i get the error : " Binding element 'paginate' implicitly has an 'any' type. and i still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to receive props:

```
export const Pagination = (totalPagesX:any, paginate :any) => {
  return <> ... </>
}
```

when props were passed as:

```
<Pagination totalPagesX={some_number} paginate={some_variable_or_function} />
```

The correct way is:

```
export const Pagination = (props) => {
  const {totalPagesX, paginate} = props // props destructuring
  return <> ... </>
}
```

Or

```
export const Pagination = ({totalPagesX, paginate}) => { // props destructuring
  return <> ... </>
}
```

To fix errors / warnings related to typescript, you can either provide correct typings or use `any`:

Example:

```
interface IProps {
  totalPagesX: number
  paginate: () => void // function
  // or, the below one, if it accepts some parameters
  paginate: (param1: number, param2: string, param3: number) => void // function
}
export const Pagination = ({totalPagesX, paginate}: IProps) => { // props destructuring
  return <> ... </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you cannot use below code inside Pagination functional component. That's not correct way in React.

```html
<Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={this.paginate} />
```

Try to use li tags only for Paging.

```js
import React from 'react';

const Pagination = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className='pagination'>
        {pageNumbers.map(number => (
          <li key={number} className='page-item'>
            <a onClick={() => paginate(number)} href='!#' className='page-link'>
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

Also make below change in your app component as well.

```js
export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {


    state: AppState = {

        currentPage: 1,
        totalPages:'10',

    }




    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            totalPages: await api.getTotalPages(),
        });
                }


     paginate(pageNumber:number) {
       console.log("number",number)
     };
     

    render() {
        const { currentPage, totalPages } = this.state;
        return (<main>
            <ThemeProvider>
                <Page />

            </ThemeProvider>
            
                <Pagination totalPages={+totalPages} paginate={this.paginate} />
            </footer>
        </main>)
    }}
```

Refer below stackblitz URL for the same.

[React Pagination](https://stackblitz.com/github/bradtraversy/simple_react_pagination?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thank you, I did like you said, but i still get the same error. I could not change this:const Pagination = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) , beacuse i get the next error :  Binding element 'paginate' implicitly has an 'any' type